# Phonegap / cordova splash screen for new iPhone 7 (plus)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, splash-screen

until the iPhone 7 came out, i used these parameters for iOS splash screens in the config.xml of my app.

```
    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

However, i noticed that the new iPhone 7 doesn't load one of my custom splash screens, but the default phonegap splash screen.

What to add?

Could this be the fix?

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/iphone7.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/iphone7plus.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1080" height="1920" />
```

I'm asking because i can't test it myself since i do not have an iPhone 7. Hence, my app already got published before i found out that he splash screen for iphone 7(plus) is incorrect.

BTW:
i use portrait orientation so no landscape is needed in my case.

Comment: Do you have the res folder on the root of your cordova project? If not, you need it there.

Comment: @Eric with all do respect, as you could've noticed, the folder is not the issue because all folders are the Same for all type of devices, and only iPhone 7 wasnt getting a correct splash screen.

Comment: ok this is just weird now.

Comment: Thats what i think 

Comment: did u solved it eventually? im having exact same issue. and tried the same..

Comment: @jony89 yes i did by adding these lines in the config i believe: <splash src="res/screen/ios/iphone7.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/iphone7plus.png" platform="ios" width="1080" height="1920" /> make sure you also create those png files with the according size ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have all resolutions in your config.xml?
Here's a sample of what I use. Hope this helps.

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen320x480.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen640x960.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen768x1024.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen1536x2048.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen1024x768.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen2048x1536.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen750x1334.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen1242x2208.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/screen2208x1242.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
```

Comment: You have confirmed the result on an iPhone 7?

Comment: Sorry can't test right now on iPhone7, also haven't had any feedback ever that my apps didn't show splash on 7....

Comment: Well, it did show, but just the default screen from phonegap. Thanks anyway!

Comment: iphone 7 plus is 1080x1920 which u don't have configured

Answer (score 0):

Although i did have the following configuration in config.xml ( under ios platform tag ) :

```
    <splash height="2208" src="images/ios/splash/Default-1242@3x~iphone6s-portrait_1242x2208.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1920" src="images/ios/splash/iphone7-portrait_1080x1920.png" width="1080" />
```

Still the splash image didn't show up. For me the problem was that the actual size of the pictures was 1242x2048. so make sure that the actual image size is exactly as specified in the splash tag element